# notifyDataChange not working with cellTemplate defined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid, celltemplate

Just starting to work with AngularJS and ui-grid, and I encounter a major issue.

My problem is as following: 
I use different ui-grid components in the same HTML page. All of those ui-grid components have one specific identifier in common.

**For example, let's take 2 ui-grid as example :**
[ui-grid N°1] identifier is defined in a row entity value.
[ui-grid N°2] identifier is defined in a column title name.

*One of my requirement:* 
When clicking on the row where the identifier is defined [ui-grid N°1], it shall highlight its entire row [ui-grid N°1] AND the entire column of the other grid [ui-grid N°2] where identifier is also defined.

The row selection isn't an issue and I succeeded to highlight the entire column of the second ui-grid thanks to specific *cellClass* function and, more important, the

```
gridApi2.core.notifyDataChange(sourceGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
```

This worked fine until I had to apply a cellTemplate option to the ui-grid N°2.

```
cellTemplate:'<span ng-click="grid.appScope.gridCtrl.cellClicked(col)">{{row.entity.name}}</span>'
```

**Now, when firing the *notifyDataChange*, nothing happens.**

If I remove the *cellTemplate* option, the refresh is done on the grid and the column is highlighted as expected.

Has anyone encountered this issue ?
If so, is there any way to refresh the grid with a *cellTemplate* option defined ?

Comment: Created a plunker to explain the issue https://plnkr.co/edit/iLwKoW0guZwG35LbGhZf?p=preview

Comment: Succeeded to do it thanks to _cellNav_ but cannot trigger action on second click (supposed to be unselection) on the same cell. Is there any way to bypass this ?

Comment: I got around this issue by delaying the call to notifyDataChange for 250ms using angular's $timeout service. The cell template code kept being run while the contents of the grid were out of sync with my grid data object. This isn't much of a solution but more of a work around which is why I'm posting here instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: Didn't think about it, that seems to be the best solution anyway if you have specific contraints and must use _cellTemplate_. Thank you for the hack and your time. +1